# PGI compilation error in Fortran: "forward reference to function"

Tags: fortran, pgi

I am a little puzzled with the PGI Fortran compiler.

When I try to compiler the following simple module stored in the file named `test.f90`, with pgfortran 19.10 I get errors that I do not understand. While compiling with gfortran or ifort run well.

The file `test.f90`:

```
MODULE CT
    IMPLICIT NONE
    integer, parameter :: si   = SELECTED_INT_KIND(4)
    integer(kind=si), public, parameter :: strlen   = 256


    type, public :: CMT
       integer (kind=si) :: nbTot 
       character(len=strlen), dimension(:), allocatable  :: condi 
    CONTAINS
       procedure :: find_line_condi 
    endtype CMT


 CONTAINS
    PURE function find_line_condi( table, cara ) result(k)
       IMPLICIT NONE
       class(CMT), intent(in)    :: table
       character(len=*), intent(in)  :: cara
       integer  (kind=si)   :: k
       integer  (kind=si)   :: j

       k=-1
       do j=1,table%nbTot
          if (trim(table%condi(j)) .eq. cara)  then
             k=j
             RETURN
          else if ( j == table%nbTot ) then
             k=-1
             RETURN
          endif
       enddo
    end function find_line_condi

END MODULE CT
```

The compilation with `pgfortran -c test.f90` returns me the following error message:

```
/opt/pgi/linux86-64-llvm/19.10/share/llvm/bin/llc: error: /opt/pgi/linux86-64-llvm/19.10/share/llvm/bin/llc: /tmp/pgfortranr2qeZBujkwvA.ll:23:77: error: invalid forward reference to function 'ct_find_line_condi_' with wrong type: expected 'i32 (i64*, i64*, i64*, i64)*' but was 'i16 (i64*, i64*, i64*, i64)*'
@ct$cmt$td$vft = global [1 x i8*] [i8* bitcast(i16 (i64*, i64*, i64*, i64)* @ct_find_line_condi_ to i8*)]
```

Does anyone has some ideas where this problem comes from?

Comment: That's the sort of error message from a compiler which, even if you have terrible Fortran code, is so incomprehensible as a diagnostic message to be worth a bug report to the vendor.  If you have a support agreement with PGI please report to them.

Comment: `SELECTED_INT_KIND(4)` do you really want half-precision integer? I suspect that error has something to do with this... Try using `si = INT32` from `iso_fortran_env` intrinsic module and see if it compiles.

Comment: @jcerar yes I need it. But you are right using iso_fortran_env int32 is a way to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the compiler.  Consider the module

```
MODULE CT
    IMPLICIT NONE

    type CMT
    CONTAINS
      procedure, nopass :: find_line_condi 
    endtype CMT

 CONTAINS
    function find_line_condi()
       integer(SELECTED_INT_KIND(4)) find_line_condi
       find_line_condi=0
    end function find_line_condi

END MODULE CT
```

which is quite a bit simpler than that of that question.  Compiled with pgfortran 19.10 there is a similar gibberish output.  It's left as an exercise to the reader/PGI support desk whether this simpler code is valid Fortran which should be accepted but I would consider the poor diagnostic to be something PGI would prefer to avoid.

However, this appears to be a weakness in the LLVM frontend of PGI: consider compiling with `pgfortran -c -Mnollvm ...`.  There are also ways to rewrite the code to attempt to work around this bug, such as changing the kind of the function result.

---

More widely, PGI [introduced](https://www.pgroup.com/products/new-features-2019.htm) in the 2019 releases the LLVM code generator.  This seems to be going through a number of [teething difficulties](https://www.pgroup.com/userforum/search.php?keywords=non-llvm).  If you have code unexpectedly failing with PGI 2019 (which may have worked with 2018), then compiling with `-Mnollvm` to use the non-LLVM generator is worth a try.

Comment: according to your comment, I will create an account and report this problem. 
Otherwise, the option `-Mnollvm` solves the problem, but since the LLVM seems to become their new standard (and might be the only option in the future) it worth mention them the situation.

Comment: Thanks: as a very active user of Fortran compilers I encourage people to report bugs.  Even if you have a workaround other people benefit from better compilers.

Comment: It is done, and I completely agree about this community behaviour.